# How can I show all Jenkins jobs in one view, even if they are contained in folders?

Tags: jenkins

I want to see *all* jobs that are defined on our Jenkins.

We use folders to structure our jobs, yet we also would like to have an overview view of all jobs without this folder structure, i.e., a flattened list of our jobs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first step is to create a new view:

[image: Create new view]

This view has to be named and as view type one has to select "*List View*":

[image: Name and select "List View"]

In the configuration view, following points have to be set:

- Recurse in subfolders: yes
- Use a regular Expression to include jobs into the view: yes
- Regular expression: `.*`

[image: Enter all settings]

---

---

This lists all jobs running on Jenkins in one view.

Comment: @CalinVlasin If you answer your own question, you have to wait 2 days. ;)
I just wanted to add this Q&A because it think it was not yet on StackOverflow and I think it could be useful to others in the future. :)